# Loading X509Certificate2 certificate chain from store

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, client-certificates, x509certificate2

I have a file (.p12) that contains 3 certificates (chained together) password-protected, that i have installed on my store. 
I'm trying to load them to my code.
The way I load them from the file is like this:

```
 var clientCert = new X509Certificate2(@"myfile.p12", "mypassword");
```

How can i achieve the same result while loading them from the store?

I've tried:

```
var computerCaStore = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine); 
computerCaStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly); 
var certificates = computerCaStore.Certificates.OfType<X509Certificate2>().ToLi‌​st(); 
var certFromStore = certificates.Single(c => c.Thumbprint == thumbprintMerchant);
var newCert = new X509Certificate2(certFromStore.RawData, "mypassword");
```

Comment: If the first line is representative of your code then `clientCert` is not 3 certs chained, but only the cert which had a private key. The second line isn't capable of producing the error you showed, so there's clearly more context.  Like, how you got `certFromStore` in the first place.

Comment: When i import the same file in the store i get 3 certificates, but when load it from the code, it is a cert with a private key. So how can i get the same from the store?

This is how i load them from the store:

       `var computerCaStore = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

computerCaStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

    var certificates = computerCaStore.Certificates.OfType<X509Certificate2>().ToList();

    var clientCertificat1 = certificates.Single(c => c.Thumbprint == thumbprintMerchant);`

I use the thumbprint

Comment: Please edit the question for context. Your sample code in the comment doesn't match the question, making it hard to reason about anything.

Comment: @GabrielAndrei how did you resolve this?

Comment: @wandos if i remember correctly, i ended up saving the RawCertData (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.getrawcertdata(v=vs.110).aspx) in the database and load the certificate that way instead of using the Store.

Comment: @GabrielAndrei i used the certFromStore instead of creating a new one. and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`certFromStore` should be equivalent to `clientCert`, the last line is what's breaking you.

The `RawData` property on `X509Certificate2` returns the DER-encoded value for the certificate, not the original file bytes.  A certificate does not have a private key, so the last line strips it away.  Your question had previously mentioned a TLS exception, and that is because your cert no longer has a private key.

If `certFromStore.HasPrivateKey` is false, then whatever you did to put the certificate into the store didn't work the way you think it did.  It's pretty unusual for a certificate with a private key to be in the Root store.