# ASP.NET Core IdentityServer4 in Production **Workflow**

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I'm new to IdentityServer4(just implemented on development environment) and I'm a little bit lost with all the configuration required for a real **world/production deployment**

So far, I have made my own search about it but can't seem to find any concrete answer on what technologies/topics I need to be familiar with in order to actually make it happen in PRODUCTION!

All I can find are a bunch of topics which answer some different questions about it but I could't find an answer with a proper **PRODUCTION IDENTITYSERVER4 WORKFLOW**

Right now I'm stuck with **AddSigningCredential()** method(not sure of how to set it up for Production environment)

Please, if there is any topic that I need to be familiar with in order to deploy in production, let me know

My main issue right now is:
What are the best practices for Production version of IdentityServer4?

I've successfully configured the IdentityConfiguration class, the client and the API which access the resources, not a problem.
My main problem is:

## HOW TO DO IT IN PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT???

This is my code so far:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
    new ApiScope[]
    {
        new("apiresources.read"),
        new("apiresources.write")
    };

public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources =>
new ApiResource[]
{
    new("apiresources")
    {
        Scopes = new List<string> { "apiResources.read", "apiResources.write" },
        ApiSecrets = new List<Secret> { new("85GxZALbqR".Sha256()) }
    }
};

public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
    new Client[]
    {
        new()
        {
            ClientId = "theclientid",
            ClientName = "GatewayApi",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
            ClientSecrets = { new Secret("ShRzsoZaRf".Sha256()) },
            AllowedScopes = { "apiresources.read", "apiresources.write" }
        },
    };

public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
    new IdentityResource[]
    {
        new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
        new IdentityResources.Profile(),
    };

    builder.Services
        .AddIdentityServer()
        .AddInMemoryClients(IdentityConfiguration.Clients)
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(IdentityConfiguration.IdentityResources)
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(IdentityConfiguration.ApiResources)
        .AddInMemoryApiScopes(IdentityConfiguration.ApiScopes)
        .AddTestUsers(IdentityConfiguration.TestUsers)
        .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

So, two things:

```
- What pre-knowledge I must have in order to be able to implement Identity(In production)

- What is the right documentation to start with
```

So far I have read:

[How to deploy to production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72639549/asp-net-core-identity-how-to-deploy-to-production)
[AddSignInCredential for IS4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49042474/addsigningcredential-for-identityserver4)
[How to configure identity server in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68954874/how-to-configure-identityserver-in-asp-net-core-3-1-production)
[How to generate and add a signin key for IS4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60772007/how-to-generate-and-add-a-signing-key-for-identity-server-4)
[Loading x509certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43278275/loading-x509certificate2-certificate-chain-from-store)
[How to retrieve all certificates in your x509store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729302/how-to-retrieve-all-certificates-in-your-x509store)

Comment: A lot of the things to succeed in production are general to any ASP.NET Core application, like configuring the Data Protection API key, the AddSigningCredential method needs a key, this key needs to be stored somewhere persistent, like Azure KeyVault or file/DB. I do have some related blog posts about auth in .NET here https://nestenius.se/